# MS Access 2013 syntax error in create table statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

This will not run. Does anyone know why?

```
Create Table Customer
(CustomerID Number(15,0)  AutoIncrement Not Null,
Name Varchar(40) Not Null,
Phone Varchar(20),
Email Varchar(40) Not Null,
Primary Key(CustomerID)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Number(15, 0)` segment:

```
Create Table Customer
(
    CustomerID AutoIncrement Not Null,
    Name Varchar(40) Not Null,
    Phone Varchar(20),
    Email Varchar(40) Not Null,
    Primary Key(CustomerID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this?

```
   CurrentDb.Execute "Create Table Customer" & _
              "(CustomerID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ," & _
              "Name Varchar(40) Not Null," & _
              "Phone Varchar(20)," & _
              "Email Varchar(40) Not Null)"
```